# Why does Solve give me an expression with root in it for this equation?

Tags: equation-solving

"12.0.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (April 6, 2019)"

This can be solved by hand without too much difficulty.  But

```
Solve[{s == 8/27 ((Sqrt[1 + (3/2 t)^2])^3 - 1), t > 0}, t, Reals]
```

results in

```
{{t -> ConditionalExpression[
    Root[-16 s - 27 s^2 + 16 #1^2 + 36 #1^4 + 27 #1^6 &, 2], s > 0]}}
```

Comment: `InverseFunction[Function[t, 8/27 ((Sqrt[1 + (3/2 t)^2])^3 - 1)]]`

Comment: For this particular problem why not just solve for $t^2$?  `Solve[{s == 8/27 ((Sqrt[1 + (3/2)^2 t2])^3 - 1), t2 > 0}, t2, Reals] // ToRadicals` results in `{{t2 -> ConditionalExpression[1/9 (-4 + (64 + 432 s + 729 s^2)^(1/3)), s > 0]}}`.

Comment: Or more straightforward:  `Solve[{s == 8/27 ((Sqrt[1 + (3/2 t)^2])^3 - 1), t > 0}, t, 
  Reals] // ToRadicals` results in `{{t -> ConditionalExpression[-(1/3) Sqrt[-4 + ((8 + 27 s)^2)^(1/3)], s > 0]}}`.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
Module[{s},
 s[t_] := 8/27 ((Sqrt[1 + (3/2 t)^2])^3 - 1);
 InverseFunction[s]["t"]
 ]
```